# Sudo requires password after adding user to sudoers

Tags: permissions, sudo, password, user-management

I have added my user in sudoers file, after a restart ubuntu still requires password to execute command.

Below is my sudoers file.

```
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d

aman    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Here "aman" is current loggedin user name.

Actually in my ubuntu 16.04 I am facing wifi issue which I am able to resolve using below command but I want to execute this command on startup without prompting for password.

```
systemctl restart network-manager.serviceroot
```

I have also tried below command but no sucess, every time I am going to execute command ubuntu prompt me to enter password.

```
usermod -aG sudo username
```

UPDATE :- Now below is my sudoers file screen shot

[image]

Note:- When I execute whoami command terminal shows "aman"

Below is the image shows me as i am administrator
[image]

Comment: The command is `ystemctl restart network-manager.service` without  "root" at the end.  What you want to do is a tremendous bad use of privilege separation which is here to protect your system.

Answer (score 4):

You should use NOPASSWD option

```
aman ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

However, I would not recommend it that way, because user `aman` can execute anything without password. I would only allow the systemctl command to be executed without password like this:

```
aman     ALL=NOPASSWD:/bin/systemctl
```

It is safer that way.

Comment: thanks for reply but this also not works, ubuntu still aks me for password.

Comment: this is *much* safer than @Félicien's suggestion to add NOPASSWD:ALL (no password required to run any program)

Answer (score 3):

This is the normal behaviour, being in the sudoers list only means that you can use the `sudo` command, but you'll be asked for your password.

If you want to use sudo without password, you need to add `NOPASSWD:ALL` after `aman    ALL=(ALL:ALL)` in `/etc/sudoers`

(the line would look like `aman    ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL`)

see [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-running-sudo-command-without-a-password/)

Comment: thanks for reply but this also not works, ubuntu still aks me for password.

Comment: weird ... I just tried and it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if its too late to answer. But I ran into same problem recently and nothing was working. So in case you login to server using ssh keys without password, you can try below steps:

1. Add user to sudoers file.

```
sudo visudo
username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

2. Then delete the password for user.

```
sudo passwd -d `whoami`
```

Now you will be able to run any sudo commands without password.

Comment: Deleting the user's password is a bad idea.

Comment: This is only in case the login is based on keys mechanism and not using any passwords for login.